# Issue adding a development swift package to an app

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to add a local in-development Swift Package to my project. I followed this [Organizing Your Code with Local Packages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/organizing_your_code_with_local_packages). Using Xcode 12 beta.

I created a swift package named "MyLibrary".
Then I move the code from my app to the **Sources** folder in my swift package.
I then close the swift package project in Xcode and drag and drop the package folder to my app.

However, here is where I am stuck. I need to add MyLibrary target into the **Link binary with Libraries** section in the build phases. I don't see the library/ framework target listed in the dialog.

I am listing below just the products and targets for the swift package. I tried adding a binaryTarget too, but that did not help.

```
products: [
    .library(
        name: "MyLibrary",
        targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
],
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "MyLibrary",
        dependencies: []),
    .testTarget(
        name: "MyLibraryTests",
        dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
]
```

Comment: Try quitting Xcode and starting it up again. Open only the project, not the package. I find that dragging a package into an existing project doesn’t work if both are open.

Comment: @matt haha, funnily enough I did encounter that issue, but I went through https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-add-local-swift-package-as-dependency/26457
where you had suggested the solution above and it worked like a charm. But this is a different issue I have. I cannot see the target listed in the build phases > link binary with libraries. I tried closing xcode completely, creating another swift package from scratch, but the issue still persits.

Comment: Well, I can create and link a working package. Start over and this time add the package to the top level of your existing project at the time you create it, not by dragging later.

Comment: Ok, now I found what went wrong. I had a simple dependency injection code written up in the main application and wanted to move it to the library. I moved the file directly under Sources (Sources>DI.swift), and since now the "MyLibrary" folder inside Sources is not required, I deleted it. That was the problem. You need to place the files inside the MyLibrary folder inside the Sources folder (Sources>MyLibrary>DI.swift). Thanks for your help, @matt

Comment: Yes, you can delete the tests if you also modify the package manifest, but the overall structure of the package is absolutely fixed and you must not change it.

Answer (score -1):

I will give step by step instructions. We will start completely from scratch in this example.

1. File > New > Project. Select the iOS App template. Save the project as My Project; other settings Storyboard, UIKit App Template, Swift. Create it on the Desktop.
2. File > New > Swift Package. Okay, this is the hard part. See at the bottom of the save dialog where it says Add to? Choose MyProject. The Group should then be MyProject too. Both icons should be blue project icons. Now save as MyLibrary, on the Desktop.
3. Now we are in MyProject. Select MyProject, the project, at the top of the project navigator. On the right, choose the target MyProject. Scroll down to Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content and click the Plus button. You will see right at the top Workspace, then MyLibrary the "framework", the MyLibrary the "library". Choose the third one, MyLibrary the "library", and click Add.